# Js compress by uglify-js give error Unexpected token: name ($)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, bootstrap-4, uglifyjs

I am compress my js files by **`uglify-js`** 
   I want to compress Bootstrap 4 js file but it give me Error like this.
   Can I compress all js files by only `uglify-js` **Or** how can i do it.

```
    Parse error at src\bootstrap\alert.js:1,7
    import $ from 'jquery'
           ^
    ERROR: Unexpected token: name ($)
```

my `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.6",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "uglify-js": "^3.1.9"
  }
```

Comment: try `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT it's not working it same error

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **ES6** version of uglify-js. Replace with this in your `package.json`

`"uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony"`

or via command line:

`npm install --save uglify-js@github:mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony`

Comment: After install `uglify-js2` I am getting this error
 `throw new JS_Parse_Error(message, line, col, pos);`

Comment: You don't want `uglify-js2`

Answer (score 0):

uglify-js does not support ES2015 syntax like import statements or arrow functions. Instead, use the [uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) module:

```diff
-    "uglify-js": "^3.1.9"
+    "uglify-es": "^3.1.9"
```

Comment: It's give me another error `const Modal = (() => {`
      
`ERROR: Modal redeclared`